# status returned as 0 on api call in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

```
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  banners: any;
  url = 'localhost:9000/api/banners';
  ngOnInit() {
  this.getBanners();
  }

   getBanners(): any {
        return this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(res=>{
          this.banners = res;
        })
  }


}
```

I am getting an unknown error with status code as 0. Where as in Postman I am getting data.

Comment: did you try prefixing `http://` to url ? Also please give stacktrace / reproducible sample to debug

Comment: Yes, I did. still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CORS` - Cross Origin Resource Sharing problem. Download any browser extension to enable it. Or make an interceptor that adds appropriate header before making api calls.